# The Angular code does not work when used within a custom library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, package

I created an angular library (Say, XYZ) that has a directive, and I am using it locally in one of my angular applications, Everything works well, and the application can now use the directive of the library(XYZ). But, I get an error as seen below:

[image]

Now, I resolved this error by adding the following providers in the library's(XYZ) directive's decorator:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[autosuggest]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: AutosuggestionDirective,// AutosuggestionDirective: Directive's name
    },
  ],
})
```

But now, I am getting this error:

[image]

Here is my package.json of the XYZ Library for your reference:

```
{
  "name": "sheshnaag",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build-project": "ng build @sheshnaag/sheshnaag --configuration production",
    "watch-project": "ng build @sheshnaag/sheshnaag --watch",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^15.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

Everything works if I shift all the code in the angular application instead of creating a separate library, but the angular library is what I am targeting.

Now, after debugging and exploring I am unable to find what this error refers to and how to resolve it. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you check if `useExisting: forwardRef(() => AutosuggestionDirective)` solves your issue ?

Comment: @Random `firstCreatePass` is a function of Angular's DI system.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, this doesn't change anything, still giving the same error, what could be another solution to it.